# Duda sobre validacion de un objeto para registrarlo en la BD

Tags: javascript, nodejs, rendimiento

Hola quiero validar los valores de las propiedades un objeto (un usuario) antes de ingresarlo a la BD, mi duda es si, lo estoy haciendo bien o estoy sobrecargando el servidor de mi API (planeo subirlo a HEROKU) con tantos `if` (a mas propiedades tenga los objetos mas if)

Aqui el codigo `/services/user.js`:

```
const userValidate = (user) => {
    if (typeof user === User) {
        if (!validator.isUUID(user.idUser || '')) return false
        if (!validator.isLength(user.names || '', { min: 3, max: 25 })) return false
        if (!validator.isLength(user.lastname || '', { min: 3, max: 50 })) return false
        if (!validator.isEmail(user.email || '')) return false
        if (!validator.isStrongPassword (user.password || '', { minLength: 8, minLowercase: 1, minUppercase: 1, minNumbers: 1, minSymbols: 1})) return false
        if (!validator.isUUID(user.idRol || '')) return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Al ver esta linea: `user === User` supongo que usas algún tipo de ORM/ODM. Si es el caso, dicho ORM/ODM seguramente ya tiene incorporado un validador a nivel de la definición de esquema del Modelo. ¿Porqué usar además otra validación sobre el objeto ya instanciado? Usualmente la validación que pretendes hacer se hace sobre los datos recibidos desde el cliente, y si los mismo son "válidos", se procede a instanciar un objeto del Modelo, con los datos previamente validados/sinitizados. Saludos

Comment: Ah no, no uso ningun ORM, no se si esta bien, estoy aprendiendo, pero ese es un DTO que tiene los datos, y solo valido para ver si ese objeto (dto) es del tipo USER, para hacer mi validacion, mis consultas son complejas, por eso no uso un ORM. Mi pregunta era si hacer tantos "if" iba a sobrecargar el servidor de la API o algo asi.

Comment: Si usas un DTO, la lógica de validación de los datos podrías incluirla en el mismo DTO. Supongo que `user` es una instancia de `User`, por lo cual usarás algún constructor. Puedes validar los datos durante la creación del objeto. De esta forma no necesitas volver a validarlos. En todo caso, hacerlo en el constructor o como un paso adicional, no tiene porqué impactar en el desempeño de tu aplicación. Si tu modelo de datos tiene 20 valores diferentes, vas a tener que validar los 20 valores, aunque eso implique 20 sentencias `if`, o 20 métodos diferentes dentro de una función de validación.

Comment: Eso me parece una respuesta razonable, podrias ponerlo como respuesta.